# AWS Nginx force routing http to https single instance EB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having an issue with the routing from AWS Elastic Beanstalk single instance from force routing http to https. I've been doing tons of research and have tried over 27+ deployments and reading all the errors on the error.log only to have become super stumped.

Recent deployments i've been getting errors about not enough worker_connections. But I wasn't getting this before.

When I first started I was getting an infinite rerouting loop. Help!

files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    owner: root
    content: |

```
  server {
      listen 8081;
      server_name example.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen       443 ssl;
      server_name  example.com;

      ssl                  on;
      ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

      ssl_session_timeout  5m;

      ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
      error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;

      location / {
          proxy_pass  https://localhost;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;             
      }
  }
```

Comment: Isn't the NodeJS app bound to port 8081? You should be configuring Nginx to listen on port 8080, not 8081.

Comment: I tried 8080, for some reason I wasn't getting anything. But I'll try it again.

Comment: so I tried that and got, 2017/02/15 23:29:35 [alert] 16739#0: *1022 1024 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:443/", host: "example.com"